# How to invoke impala-shell using ldap from a script?

Tags: shell, openldap, cloudera-cdh, impala

I've installed CDH 5.4 and latest version of Impala (2.2.0) along with OpenLDAP. While invoking impala-shell in interactive mode, all works well as the password is not visible. However, I want to run this arrangement in a shell script. If I give:

`impala-shell -l -u testuser -f /path/to/file`

It does ask for the password which I have to provide manually. Can this be automated using any other parameter? Is there any parameter akin to "-w" parameter of Beeline, so that the password can be secured?

Any help will be much appreciated.